# Oracle will not start with ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated

Tags: oracle

I'm in need of urgent help with this one.

My Oracle 11gR2, running on a VM, crashed when the datastore of the host filled up. I got the VM to start and as I'm trying to start the DB, I see this:

```
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1987563520 bytes
Fixed Size                  2229704 bytes
Variable Size            1476397624 bytes
Database Buffers          503316480 bytes
Redo Buffers                5619712 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
Process ID: 3929
Session ID: 1 Serial number: 5
```

The alert log contains this:

```
ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id 1615598463
Database mounted in Exclusive Mode
Lost write protection disabled
Completed: ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
Fri Nov 05 12:43:47 2021
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
Beginning crash recovery of 1 threads
Started redo scan
Completed redo scan
 read 5129 KB redo, 867 data blocks need recovery
Started redo application at
 Thread 1: logseq 16580, block 11139
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 2 Seq 16580 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo02.log
Completed redo application of 2.76MB
Completed crash recovery at
 Thread 1: logseq 16580, block 21398, scn 406093127
 867 data blocks read, 860 data blocks written, 5129 redo k-bytes read
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 16581 (thread open)
Thread 1 opened at log sequence 16581
  Current log# 3 seq# 16581 mem# 0: /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo03.log
Successful open of redo thread 1
MTTR advisory is disabled because FAST_START_MTTR_TARGET is not set
SMON: enabling cache recovery
[3929] Successfully onlined Undo Tablespace 2.
Undo initialization finished serial:0 start:4294873730 end:4294873790 diff:60 (0 seconds)
Verifying file header compatibility for 11g tablespace encryption..
Verifying 11g file header compatibility for tablespace encryption completed
SMON: enabling tx recovery
Database Characterset is AL32UTF8
No Resource Manager plan active
replication_dependency_tracking turned off (no async multimaster replication found)
Starting background process QMNC
Process QMNC died, see its trace file
Errors in file /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_3929.trc:
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
Errors in file /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_3929.trc:
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
Errors in file /home/oracle/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_3929.trc:
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
Error 450 happened during db open, shutting down database
USER (ospid: 3929): terminating the instance due to error 450
Instance terminated by USER, pid = 3929
ORA-1092 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE OPEN...
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (3929) as a result of ORA-1092
Fri Nov 05 12:43:51 2021
ORA-1092 : opitsk aborting process
```

The trace file for QNMC shows this:

```
*** 2021-11-05 12:43:48.205
Completed redo application of 2.76MB

*** 2021-11-05 12:43:48.343
Completed recovery checkpoint
----- Recovery Hash Table Statistics ---------
Hash table buckets = 262144
Longest hash chain = 1
Average hash chain = 867/867 = 1.0
Max compares per lookup = 1
Avg compares per lookup = 26276/32586 = 0.8
----------------------------------------------
Recovery sets nab of thread 1 seq 16580 to 21398 with 8 zeroblks
kwqmnich: current time:: 10: 43: 48: 0
kwqmnich: instance no 0 repartition flag 1
kwqmnich: initialized job cache structure

*** 2021-11-05 12:43:49.876
Process QMNC is dead (pid=3931 req_ver=1 cur_ver=1 state=KSOSP_SPAWNED).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trace Bucket Dump Begin: default bucket for process 19 (osid: 3929)
TIME(*=approx):SEQ:COMPONENT:FILE@LINE:FUNCTION:SECT/DUMP: [EVENT#:PID:SID] DATA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-11-05 12:43:48.876672 :80035B07:db_trace:ksb.c@2342:ksbs1p_real(): [10254:19:1] KSBS1P: process USER trying to start background QMNC
2021-11-05 12:43:48.876675 :80035B08:db_trace:ksb.c@2405:ksbs1p_real(): [10254:19:1] KSBS1P: process USER obtained PR enqueue to start background QMNC
2021-11-05 12:43:49.876615 :80035B3A:db_trace:ksb.c@2609:ksbs1p_real(): [10254:19:1] KSBS1P: out of loop: process did not start
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trace Bucket Dump End: default bucket for process 19 (osid: 3929)
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start
ORA-00450: background process 'QMNC' did not start
ORA-00443: background process "QMNC" did not start

*** 2021-11-05 12:43:49.900
USER (ospid: 3929): terminating the instance due to error 450
```

I was thinking of running  a "startup mount" followed by a "recover database" but I don't want to take any chances.

Please help me get the database to start.

Comment: Nothing on a Free Forum is "urgent". I suggest you contact Oracle Support for this. Also, please show all 4 digits of your DB version (eg 11.2.0.4)

Comment: The alert log believes the recovery was completed successfully. I would make sure the instance is fully shutdown (confirming processes have all been removed) then start it up bit by bit (nomount, mount, open). If that gives the same problem, start it up with `AQ_TM_PROCESSES  = 0` (temporarily, once it's working you'd want to remove this), this will mean QMNC isn't needed to start - it may fail with another process in which case you may get an easier to follow error.

Comment: You did confirm that the disk space issues are resolved on all drives Oracle is using? If so, I agree with @MichaelKutz that you're going to need to open a ticket with Oracle. And you should confirm you have solid backups sitting nearby, as Oracle support, in my experience, often resorts to "reinstall everything and restore from backup" when I've dealt with them.

Comment: Google-Fu tells me this can also be a controlfile corruption issue or an out of memory issue.